# The mouse is not working on window, but works perfectly fine in the ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mouse

I am very new to Linux, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday, and now after successfully dual boot the system, the mouse is not working in my window but it works perfectly fine in Ubuntu. I seek help but, mostly they address the opposite.

What should I do now?

Comment: Ask Windows support.  This is AskUbuntu.Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: But the problems started when i installed ubuntu

Comment: Installing Ubuntu makes zero changes to Windows applications or Windows hardware drivers. Do your troubleshooting on the Windows side.

Comment: I uninstall the ubuntu and now my driver is working fine